# Parsing XML data by Null Value in Nifi

Tags: xml, tcp, apache-nifi

Currently receiving data in NiFi using the 'GetTCP' connection. The streaming data that is coming from the connection has XML data that is parsed out by Null values.

How would I be able to parse this flowfile or XML so that each will be a separate flowfile/XML file?
Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<event>
</event>
NULL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<event>
</event>
```

I would like this broken out so that it is two separate XML flowfiles. Is there an existing NiFi processor that is capable of splitting this up?

Comment: sounds like SplitContent should be enough for you

Comment: Thank you @daggett! Used the SplitContent processor as you've recommended and updated the properties with hexadecimal format and byte value of '00' which did the trick. If you leave an answer instead of an answer, will mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like `SplitContent` should be enough for you.

just play with `Byte Sequence` parameters that act as a delimiter

Comment: Marked as answer. Thanks again